# LARAVEL: Use a javascript variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I would like to get an id from a button. I need this id in my ajax request. This is my button:

```
 <form>
      <div class="form-group">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" name="deletecar" id="{{$car->id}}">Delete</button>
      </div>
 </form>
```

I'm getting the id of the button this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var JcarID = this.id;</script>
```

Finally my Ajax Request.

```
$('[name="deletecar"]').click(function (e)
        {
            var JcarId = this.id;
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{ action('CarController@delete', [$user->id, $car->id])}}',
                success: function (data)
                {
                  //   alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Thx for reading!

**SOLUTION**

Changed some bits in my code. I changed the url of my request.

```
$('[name="deletecar"]').click(function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/users/{{$user->id}}/deletecar/'+this.id,
                success: function (data)
                {
                  //   alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: use another variable in Javascript and assign the value on pageload like : var carID = {{ $car->id }} if you want to compare the value in javascript compare directly or if you want to compare the value in php, pass the variable value via Ajax

Comment: But this would only work for one car. What if you have 10 cars on the same screen?

Comment: As per the update OP can directly pass th variable JcarId, via AJAX. & i think he already got solution

Comment: Idk if its better, but I changed the url a bit. Not using the action propertie. Just sending the id in the url :P Works aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess what is your requirement yet either if you want to get the button id value

this.attr('id'); or this.prop('id');

Or if you want to set the id value of button

$('[name="deletecar"]').attr('id', yourvalue)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use JcarId rather $car->id in ajax request. Here what you can do rather than directly using PHP code in ajax call.

```
$('[name="deletecar"]').click(function (e)
        {
            var JcarId = this.id;
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/CarController/delete',
                data: {'carId':JcarId}
                success: function (data)
                {
                  //   alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Was thinking about that yes, Have changed the URL so my request sends the variable to the route.